# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, traceback

```
pwd = ''
gmail = ''

def open_driver(driver=None):
        if driver == None:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    
            # Go to the sign in link
            driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=ar&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")
    
            # Account box
            acnt_box = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
            acnt_box.click()
            # Enter the gmail
            acnt_box.send_keys(gmail)
    
            # Click on the 'Next' button
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/div[1]').click()
    
            # Password box
            pwd_box = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
            pwd_box.click()
            pwd_box.send_keys(pwd)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\LenovoPc\Desktop\Projects\My own projects\Facebook Bot\code.py", line 66, in <module>
    open_driver()
  File "c:\Users\LenovoPc\Desktop\Projects\My own projects\Facebook Bot\code.py", line 28, in open_driver
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span]').click()    
  File "C:\Users\LenovoPc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\LenovoPc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\LenovoPc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)
```

So what's the solution for every report in the output?

Note that this is a code to google sign in.You can test it by just entering youre gmail & password
I want this auto google sign in for a facebook bot.

Comment: The XPATH in the error message (`'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/button/span]'`) is invalid, but it doesn't seem to appear in your code. Can you delete that bracket at the end and try again?

Comment: Your question heading is _`NoSuchElementException`_ where as error tracelogs says _`InvalidSelectorException`_